# Second dropdown changes after select first dropdown

Tags: python, selenium, drop-down-menu

I have two drop-downs on single page. 
I can identify them by Ids

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.ncdex.com/MarketData/FuturePrices.aspx")

dd_Commodity = driver.find_element_by_id('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder3_ddlCommodity')
dd_ExpiryDate = driver.find_element_by_id('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder3$ddlExpiryDate')
```

I can select the values in the FIRST dropdown perfectly... No issues atall

```
dd_Commodity.send_keys('SOY')
dd_Commodity.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
```

But when I try to select the value in the second dropdown

```
dd_ExpiryDate.send_keys('Jun-2010')
```

I get an error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message:
    stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

The funny thing is when I select the second dropdown individually by

```
dd_ExpiryDate.send_keys('Oct-2010')
```

It works.

Looks like the SECOND dropdown values are changed on selecting the value in FIRST dropdown.

But the elementID or name ... nothing changes... but still not able to select the value in the second dropdown.

Comment: Is there any relation betweeen them? Normally, when you select value from first, is there any change?

Comment: StaleElementException means that the DOM has changed - refresh in the background, or some javascript has rebuilt the page, so the previously initialized WebElements become non-existing. First initialize the first dropdown, and select the desired value. Initialize the second dropdown only after this.

Comment: you should select by considering indexes of drop down instead of sending text.

Comment: @MahsumAkbas It worked perfectly. As you said the problem is that "WebElements become non-existing". And i should be Initialized only after selecting the first dropdown.

Thanks a million for all the help and time. 
Cheers
Vivek.

Answer (score 0):

In you case, when you select 'Soy Bean' value in first drop down, the values in second drop down will changes. But there its showing different values.
You can understand by displaying option values of second drop down in logcat.

Try to understand from the below code.

```
    driver.get("http://www.ncdex.com/MarketData/FuturePrices.aspx");
    WebElement selectFirstDDEle = driver
            .findElement(By
                    .xpath("//select[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder3_ddlCommodity']"));
    Select selectFirstDD = new Select(selectFirstDDEle);
    // selectFirstDD.selectByIndex(1);

    // or
    selectFirstDD.selectByVisibleText("Soy Bean ( SYBEANIDR )");

    // To select second drop down
    WebElement selectSecondDDEle = driver
            .findElement(By
                    .xpath("//select[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder3_ddlExpiryDate']"));
    Select selectSecondDD = new Select(selectSecondDDEle);
    List<WebElement> options = selectSecondDD.getOptions();
    for (int i = 0; i < options.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println("***** position= " + i + " text= "+ options.get(i).getText());
    }
    //selectSecondDD.selectByIndex(5);

     selectSecondDD.selectByVisibleText("Oct-2015");
```